# Oracle , Encryption or obfuscation function with output size limit

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Is there any encryption or obfuscation Oracle Function (standard or third party) that can limit the output size?

I need to obfuscate a column smaller than 20 char by limiting the output to 20 char .

I'm using the following function that generates an output of 32 Characters , the constraint comes from a System external to mine , I couldn't negotiate a larger size of the output (their input).

```
create or replace function md5 (valor varchar) return varchar2 is   
v_input varchar2(2000) := valor;   
hexkey varchar2(32) := null;   
begin   
hexkey := rawtohex(dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(input => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_input)));  
return nvl(hexkey,'');   
end;
```

I need something like obfuscate a USA Social Service in a 20 char length output.

I need also some security because us applied to private medical information.

Comment: MD5 is neither encryption nor obfuscation.  It is a hash function.  what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the response , I need to obfuscate some fields in a BI application to follow the brazilian version of GDPR. The MD5 works in this case because returns a encriptted string. I need something like obfuscate a USA Social Service in a 20 char length output.

Comment: Do you mean Social Security Number (9 digits)?   Again, MD5 is not "encryption" you can't "decrypt" an MD5 hash.  It is one-way.  What is the user of this string going to do with it?

Comment: The MD5 works in this case just because it's "one way" but I need a smaller output , that's the question. The SSN is just an example.

Comment: If you don't care about being able to reverse it, why not just substring the result?  Or return a hard-coded '999-99-9999'?

Comment: I must keep the same id to a BI application , the value appears in differentes places , must be unique to the App link it.

Comment: Pay for a license for the [data masking](https://www.oracle.com/uk/security/database-security/data-masking/) cost option and then use that? It looks like one of the 11g options for [providing a masking format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41481/tdm_data_masking.htm#RATUG4028) can encrypt the data to a specific format (but it does not guarantee a 1-to-1 mapping) and there are multiple other masking options.

Comment: With any hash algorithm, there is a risk of collisions so you can't guarantee uniqueness.  But taking the first 20 characters of an MD5 hash should have a pretty low risk of collisions.  If you don't need to limit what characters are in the string, you could represent a 128-bit MD5 hash in 16 single-byte characters assuming your database character set is a single-byte fixed-width character set.

Comment: Thanks , Excuse me for the late return , i really need a simple thing (I guess) a limited length output . I can´t see a solution with the MD5.